# Spring service will not start

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-boot

Working on a basic Spring REST service, but I seem to have a problem with running the service due to JDBC.

I have followed a simple [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm), but at the end the following error log comes up.

**Error log**

```
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.5.RELEASE)

2015-09-20 13:53:55.495  INFO 2120 --- [lication.main()] com.fenrir.webservice.Application        : Starting Application on lars-desktop with PID 2120 (D:\Development\fenrir\fenrir-webservice\target\classes started by lars in D:\Development\fenrir\fenrir-webservice)
2015-09-20 13:53:55.509  INFO 2120 --- [lication.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5b211ae1: startup date [Sun Sep 20 13:53:55 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-20 13:53:55.803  INFO 2120 --- [lication.main()] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-09-20 13:53:55.834  INFO 2120 --- [lication.main()] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/Development/fenrir/fenrir-webservice/src/main/resources/, file:/D:/Development/fenrir/fenrir-webservice/src/main/resources/, file:/D:/Development/fenrir/fenrir-webservice/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.0.0/classmate-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.14/snakeyaml-1.14.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.12/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.23/tomcat-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.12/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.6/jackson-databind-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.23/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.1.3.Final/hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.12/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.6/jackson-annotations-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.6/jackson-core-2.4.6.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.2.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.23/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.23.jar, file:/C:/Users/lars/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.1.7.RELEASE/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar]
2015-09-20 13:53:55.840 ERROR 2120 --- [lication.main()] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.fenrir.webservice.Application.main(Application.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:572)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:502)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 54 common frames omitted

2015-09-20 13:53:55.843  INFO 2120 --- [lication.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5b211ae1: startup date [Sun Sep 20 13:53:55 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-20 13:53:55.843  WARN 2120 --- [lication.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5b211ae1: startup date [Sun Sep 20 13:53:55 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.fenrir.webservice.Application.main(Application.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015-09-20 13:53:55.844  WARN 2120 --- [lication.main()] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5b211ae1: startup date [Sun Sep 20 13:53:55 CEST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.fenrir.webservice.Application.main(Application.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
    at com.fenrir.webservice.Application.main(Application.java:22)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:572)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:502)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:475)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:535)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:677)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:271)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry$OptimizedBeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:45)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 54 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.217s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 20 13:53:55 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/284M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.2.5.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project fenrir-webservice: An exception occured while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager due to internal class not found. This can happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake): org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory: org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Application.java**

```
package com.fenrir.webservice;

import com.fenrir.webservice.jdbc.CustomerJDBCTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * Created by lars on 9/19/2015.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:src/Beans.xml");

        CustomerJDBCTemplate customerJDBCTemplate = (CustomerJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("customerJDBCTemplate");
        /*
        * sql statements
        **/

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.fenrir.webservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>fenrir-webservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

The project can also be viewed on [the github repo page](https://github.com/TisLars/fenrir-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the tutorial you are following is not using Spring Boot, yet you are for some reason. `SpringApplication.run` creates its own application context, which might be the source of your problems. Either use Spring Boot and don't create the application context manually or create it manually as illustrated in the tutorial and don't use Spring Boot.

---

If you wish to use Spring Boot, you should modify your code like this:

1) Remove the manual application context creation from your main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

2) Define your data source using Spring boot properties file (`src/main/resources/application.properties`) and get rid of Beans.xml:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fenrir_customers
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

3) Modify your `CustomerJDBCTemplate` like this:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerJDBCTemplate implements CustomerDAO {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    // Rest of your methods
}
```

4) Autowire the repository in the controller, don't manually create it:

```
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDAO customerDao;
    // Controller methods ...
}
```

5) Adjust your dependencies

Remove

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I see, now it runs after I deleted the `Spring.ApplicationRun()` function. But now I can't view my service in the browser anymore, [localhost:8080/auth](http://localhost:8080/auth) returns nothing, unable to connect. I followed this guide first [Spring: Hello World](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Comment: @Lars Added approximate instructions to modify your code in order to get your custom Dao working with Spring Boot properly

Comment: I did your adjustments, but still the same (sort) error (http://pastebin.com/ukma1JsZ). I updated [my repo](https://github.com/TisLars/fenrir-service) so you can have an easy look, if possible.

Comment: @Lars I tested your code. Seems to be dependency problem (step 5). Also the CustomerJDBCTemplate must implement CustomerDAO. Hopefully it will work now.

Comment: Thank you for help, appreciated. This really helps me with my project.

Comment: Regarding step 3, just inject a `JdbcTemplate` spring boot provides one already no need to create another one.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, totally missed that. Answer updated

Comment: Unintentionally addition of these dependencies 
- `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
 <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>`
- `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
 <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>`
in a `Spring Boot` application can also cause this issue of 
- `Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin(default-cli)`
- `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition`